# Cargar procedimientos almacenados en jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

solicito su ayuda, intento sacar unos reportes en jasperreport studio
pero cuando cargo el SP no me trae los campos, el query en el procedimiento almacenado funciona bien y trae los campos adecuados en sql server y en cuanto a la lógica del mismo trabajo con un método heredado que funciona para los reportes que ya tenían hechos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

para solucionarlo hice lo siguiente:

Paso 1: Crear los parámetros que necesitamos, en este caso "crearemos 1"

Paso 2: Agregar un nombre al Parámetro, ejemplo: Nombre_Persona

Paso 3: Agregar un valor por defecto, en caso de que desde Java se envíe null
entonces tomará este valor por defecto, ejemplo: Valor por defecto "Miguel"

Paso 4: Llamar al procedimiento almacenado desde Jasper de la siguiente manera: call nombre_procedimiento($P{Nmobre_Persona}) (Enviamos el parámetro que está con un valor por defecto para poder entrar y "buscar datos").

Paso 5: Darle a buscar los campos y listo.

Comment: Por favor, amplia tu respuesta. Comparte tu información.

Comment: Estupendo. Tu mismo puedes editar tu respuesta e incorporar esa información. Si no, yo lo haré, aunque probablemente me equivoque con el formateo. Gracias.

Comment: Excelente idea, ya lo hice, gracias por tu comentario, cualquier duda favor dejarme saber y con gusto te ayudo!

Comment: El problema se daba porque el sp realizaba un procedimiento y consulta luego datos que venían de dicho procedimiento, los sps corren en paralelo al ejecutarse desde una función por lo cual la información consultada a su vez no estaba disponible, la solución fue usar un sp y una función diferente para realizar el procedimiento y usar el estándar para consultarlo